# How to preserve order in a Map created from Month.values() with java 8 streams

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I would like to create a Map by using java 8 streams but for Month.values() which is an enum that contains all the months of the year. But in my particular case I need as key the month and as value an Object with an id, name (month name) and a particular value. I did this approach first:

```
Map<String, MyOwnClass> myMap = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
        .map(month -> new MyOwnClass(month.name()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyOwnClass::getName, p -> p));
```

The problem is that the map does not have the months in natural order, I was not able to find the way to generate a Map keeping the same order, I mean, with the key starting on January, then February...and so on. I got all the months but disordered.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Luis.

Comment: _"the map does not have the months in natural order"_  -- A `Map` data structure intrinsically does not have a "natural order".  The closest thing is a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves _insertion_ order, but that applies only when iterating over the map elements.  It is not clear what behavior you are expecting would correspond with "natural order".

Comment: I need a map or as you said LinkedHashMap in this way: ["January", MyOwnClass instance], ["February", MyOwnClass instance], ["March", MyOwnClass instance], .......... ["December", MyOwnClass instance]. As you can see there, they are ordered. I would like to know how to create that by using java8-streams based on Month.values() which returns all the months of the year.

Comment: Of course, an [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) *would* preserve order.

Comment: On an abstract level, a `Map` data structure ***has no order***.  Can you explain why you believe you need it to have an order? How are you going to use it?  I suspect this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Jim,  I understood your point in regards to "Map data structure has no order" what I want to do is what I mentioned in the previous answer.

Comment: Well this is the solution I found to my problem:   `Map<Integer, Person> map = Arrays.stream(Month.values()).collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Month::getValue,
                        m -> new Person(m.name()),
                        (v1, v2) -> v1,
                        LinkedHashMap::new
                )
        );

        map.forEach(
                (k, v) -> System.out.println("key: " + Month.of(k).name() + " - value:" + v)
        );` By running this code I can have the Months in the natural order.